# Formula for Snake Draft pick numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, arithmetic

Hello I am trying to come up with a formula to calculate the overall pick number in a snake style draft.

For example in a snake draft every other round the pick order reverses. So in a 10 team league (10 picks each round) if I had pick number 10, I would have pick #10 in the first round and then pick # 1 in the second round (which would be the 11 overall pick). For round 3 I would have pick #10 third round (overall pick number of 30). Then in round 4 I would have pick #1 (overall pick number 31)...etc. The formula would require the following variables: `League Size (# of picks per round) and Pick Number (pick number for first round)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No idea what a snake style draft is, but from your description it appears thet the overall pick number is always League Size plus 1.

Comment: edited example maybe that clears it up @Hagen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are $N$ picks per round and your first pick is $n$, you pick $n,2N-n+1,2N+n, 4N-n+1, 4N+n, 6N-n+1,6N+n \ldots$  To collapse this into a formula, you pick in round $r$ is $$\begin {cases} (r-1)N+n&r \text{ odd} \\ rN-n+1 & r \text { even}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Awesome! This is great, thanks!

Comment: This answer isn't correct. Based on this formula when you have 12 teams and and your slot position is 1 you would get the following draft picks.

1, 12, 13, 24, 25, 36, 37, 48, 49

But the correct draft picks should be:

1, 24, 25, 48, 49

You need to multiply the rN by 2 for both odd and even.

Comment: @CBP:  It is correct.  In your example, the first pick comes from $r=1$ and the first line, giving $1$.  The second comes from the second line with $r=2$ and gives $24$.  The third pick comes from the first line with $r=3$ and gives $25$ as required.

Comment: You are 100% correct @RossMilikan.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some javascript code to solve this problem based on the correct answer above.

Here is the javascript code to print out the results:

```
"use strict";

// n is position
// r is round
// N is number of teams

const NumberOfTeams = 12;
const allDraftPicks = {};

for (let draftPosition = 1; draftPosition <= NumberOfTeams; draftPosition++) {
  const picks = [];

  for (let round = 1; round <= 16; round++) {
    let draftPick;

    if (round % 2 === 0) {
      draftPick = (round * NumberOfTeams) - draftPosition + 1;
    } else {
      draftPick = ((round - 1) * NumberOfTeams) + draftPosition;
    }

    picks.push(draftPick);
  }

  allDraftPicks[draftPosition] = picks;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(allDraftPicks, null, 2));
```

Here is the JSON representation of a 12 team league for 16 rounds:

```
{
      "1": [1, 24, 25, 48, 49, 72, 73, 96, 97, 120, 121, 144, 145, 168, 169, 192, 193, 216, 217, 240, 241, 264, 265, 288, 289, 312, 313, 336, 337, 360, 361, 384],
      "2": [2, 23, 26, 47, 50, 71, 74, 95, 98, 119, 122, 143, 146, 167, 170, 191, 194, 215, 218, 239, 242, 263, 266, 287, 290, 311, 314, 335, 338, 359, 362, 383],
      "3": [3, 22, 27, 46, 51, 70, 75, 94, 99, 118, 123, 142, 147, 166, 171, 190, 195, 214, 219, 238, 243, 262, 267, 286, 291, 310, 315, 334, 339, 358, 363, 382],
      "4": [4, 21, 28, 45, 52, 69, 76, 93, 100, 117, 124, 141, 148, 165, 172, 189, 196, 213, 220, 237, 244, 261, 268, 285, 292, 309, 316, 333, 340, 357, 364, 381],
      "5": [5, 20, 29, 44, 53, 68, 77, 92, 101, 116, 125, 140, 149, 164, 173, 188, 197, 212, 221, 236, 245, 260, 269, 284, 293, 308, 317, 332, 341, 356, 365, 380],
      "6": [6, 19, 30, 43, 54, 67, 78, 91, 102, 115, 126, 139, 150, 163, 174, 187, 198, 211, 222, 235, 246, 259, 270, 283, 294, 307, 318, 331, 342, 355, 366, 379],
      "7": [7, 18, 31, 42, 55, 66, 79, 90, 103, 114, 127, 138, 151, 162, 175, 186, 199, 210, 223, 234, 247, 258, 271, 282, 295, 306, 319, 330, 343, 354, 367, 378],
      "8": [8, 17, 32, 41, 56, 65, 80, 89, 104, 113, 128, 137, 152, 161, 176, 185, 200, 209, 224, 233, 248, 257, 272, 281, 296, 305, 320, 329, 344, 353, 368, 377],
      "9": [9, 16, 33, 40, 57, 64, 81, 88, 105, 112, 129, 136, 153, 160, 177, 184, 201, 208, 225, 232, 249, 256, 273, 280, 297, 304, 321, 328, 345, 352, 369, 376],
      "10": [10, 15, 34, 39, 58, 63, 82, 87, 106, 111, 130, 135, 154, 159, 178, 183, 202, 207, 226, 231, 250, 255, 274, 279, 298, 303, 322, 327, 346, 351, 370, 375],
      "11": [11, 14, 35, 38, 59, 62, 83, 86, 107, 110, 131, 134, 155, 158, 179, 182, 203, 206, 227, 230, 251, 254, 275, 278, 299, 302, 323, 326, 347, 350, 371, 374],
      "12": [12, 13, 36, 37, 60, 61, 84, 85, 108, 109, 132, 133, 156, 157, 180, 181, 204, 205, 228, 229, 252, 253, 276, 277, 300, 301, 324, 325, 348, 349, 372, 373],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are $N$ picks per round, and you want to predict your next pick number $P_{r+1}$ from your current pick number $P_r$ and current round $r$, you can use:

$$P_{r+1}=2Nr+1-P_r$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python [Serpentine System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpentine_system) generator:

```
num_teams=12
snake_picks={}
rounds=16

for pos in range(1,num_teams+1):
    picks=[]
    
    for round in range(1,rounds+1):
        if round % 2==0:
            draft_pick=(round * num_teams) - pos + 1
        else:
            draft_pick=((round - 1) * num_teams) + pos
            
        picks.append(draft_pick)
        
    snake_picks[pos]=picks
    
for pick in snake_picks:
    print(f'{pick}: {", ".join(map(str,snake_picks[pick]))}')
```

Prints:

```
1: 1, 24, 25, 48, 49, 72, 73, 96, 97, 120, 121, 144, 145, 168, 169, 192
2: 2, 23, 26, 47, 50, 71, 74, 95, 98, 119, 122, 143, 146, 167, 170, 191
3: 3, 22, 27, 46, 51, 70, 75, 94, 99, 118, 123, 142, 147, 166, 171, 190
4: 4, 21, 28, 45, 52, 69, 76, 93, 100, 117, 124, 141, 148, 165, 172, 189
5: 5, 20, 29, 44, 53, 68, 77, 92, 101, 116, 125, 140, 149, 164, 173, 188
6: 6, 19, 30, 43, 54, 67, 78, 91, 102, 115, 126, 139, 150, 163, 174, 187
7: 7, 18, 31, 42, 55, 66, 79, 90, 103, 114, 127, 138, 151, 162, 175, 186
8: 8, 17, 32, 41, 56, 65, 80, 89, 104, 113, 128, 137, 152, 161, 176, 185
9: 9, 16, 33, 40, 57, 64, 81, 88, 105, 112, 129, 136, 153, 160, 177, 184
10: 10, 15, 34, 39, 58, 63, 82, 87, 106, 111, 130, 135, 154, 159, 178, 183
11: 11, 14, 35, 38, 59, 62, 83, 86, 107, 110, 131, 134, 155, 158, 179, 182
12: 12, 13, 36, 37, 60, 61, 84, 85, 108, 109, 132, 133, 156, 157, 180, 181
```